# Spark Timestamp - Millis and RFC3339 nano

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data source provides timestamps to the nanosecond.  Ideally Id like to preserve this, however RFC3339 support for TimestampType is required and I dont think it is (or is it!)

Firstly is there a way to do this in Spark?  Im using 2.11-2.1.1 (acutally using databricks runtime 3.0)

Now I certainly want to retain the millis (for rapid event time ordering) - I could live without the nanos precision if needed.

```
val orderPlacedTimestampDF = Seq(
  ("orderPlacedDate", "2017-06-13T14:23:49.357Z")).toDF("field", "date")

val orderPlacedTimestampConvertedDF = 
   orderPlacedTimestampDF.select($"field", $"date", unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp"))

display(orderPlacedTimestampConvertedDF)


'2017-06-13T14:23:49.357Z' gets converted to '2017-06-13T14:23:49.000+0000'
```

(Note: If I add the 'Z' in to the pattern I get null back!)

Any help appreciated

Note the '.SSS' suffix on the format string.  However, this simply returns the same as the format string without .SSS.

Am I missing something here, or is there a better what to do this conversion, or does the TimestampType not support?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use nanosecond precision timestamps, you should keep them as `BIGINT`/`LongType` in your dataframes and only convert them to Spark timestamps when you need to perform non-obvious operations, e.g., timezone conversions. This way, common operations such as range filtering can be performed quickly and efficiently with no loss of precision.

If you need to perform common operations on these timestamps that are not easily handled through Spark, you can create your own UDFs and/or `Dataset[A]` implicits. At Swoop we do this a lot when it comes to time-related data, e.g., to enable partition filtering (where the time format is `yyyyMMddhhmm`) or to expose complex operations such as grouping by week.